# Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe> <0a> <ff><fe>'

Tags: r

I am trying to read in this delimited text file. It is marked as .csv but it says that it is UTF-16 Unicode Text.txt file. What am I doing wrong?

```
    df <- read.delim("/Users/admin/Downloads/data1.csv", sep = ",")

    Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>

<0a>

<ff><fe>'

    warnings()
    Warning messages:
    1: In grep("^[^#].*", lines, value = TRUE) :
      input string 1 is invalid in this locale
    2: In read.table(path, encoding = encoding, header = header,  ... :
      line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

Comment: How does your data look like?

Comment: You have an encoding problem/mismatch and you are not telling us enough to offer any specific assistance.

Comment: i'm not sure what kind of info I need to provide to ask for assistance. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to input the correct Encoding.

I've never had this error before, maybe they've changed the default options of read function arguments.

Today i got the same error while reading a csv file with complex column names, solved using `fileEncoding='latin1'` and also took the opportunity to add `check.names = F` to avoid have spaces replaced by dots.

`mydata<-read.csv('my_dataset.csv',fileEncoding='latin1',check.names=F)`

or

`mydata<-read.csv2('my_dataset.csv',fileEncoding='latin1',check.names=F)`

Answer (score 4):

I got same error while I was reading a `.csv` file:

> invalid multibyte string at

Have a look at `FileEconding`. In my case, I've sorted using: `fileEncoding="latin1"`

Here are the docs:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Encoding